# How to allow sysadmin to create role?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**SYSADMIN** role cannot create roles at the moment or at least that's what I learned from the docs. Does anyone know how to allow SYSADMIN to create roles?

Comment: You can grant the CREATE ROLE privilege to a role.  Why not create a custom role that meets your needs instead of manipulating a system-defined role?  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#global-privileges

Comment: @SuzyLockwood Your comment is actually the best answer.  I suggest posting it as an answer.

Comment: @SuzyLockwood yes it is well suited as an answer to my question and yes it solves my problem. I like the idea of creating a separate role. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, it is an answer now.  Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grant the CREATE ROLE privilege to a role. Why not create a custom role that meets your needs instead of manipulating a system-defined role?  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#global-privileges